# jQuery focus on first form field in div after using .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following example (simplified to help others) where an error class is added if fields don't meet basic validation requirements:

```
  var email = $("input#email").val();
     if (email == "") {
     $("#emailblock").addClass("has-error")
  var prevent = 1;
  }

  var org = $("input#organisation").val();
  if (org == "") {
     $("#orgblock").addClass("has-error")
  var prevent = 1;
  }

// if no entry, prevent submission and highlight first field
  if (prevent == '1') {
     $(".has-error:first").focus();
  }
```

However, using the above code doesn't focus on the first instance of `.has-error` after  using `addClass()`.

How can you select the first instance of `has-error` or any other dynamically assigned class after using `.addClass` to a `<div>` that contains a form element?

Comment: is `#emailblock` a div?

Comment: and you still want to focus on the first input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) on `<input>`, `<select>`, `<a href>` etc

change `$(".has-error:first").focus();` to `$(".has-error:first input").focus();`

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lajjv19/4/)

Comment: Awesome :) No problem